# What is Jibril's favorite game called?

Tags: no-game-no-life

Jibril only plays one game, and there's an episode (or more) dedicated to her playing the game with the siblings.  However, on the wiki page, it doesn't say the name of the game, nor can I find it anywhere else.

As I recall, it starts with an S.

Answer (score 3):

Shiritori

Here's an article about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiritori) and here's the [NGNL version](https://no-game-no-life.fandom.com/wiki/Materialization_Shiritori) from episode 6. Players take turns saying a noun which begins with the final kana (i.e. syllable) in the previous word, words cannot be repeated, first person to take too long or say a word ending in ん (the n sound) loses since no word in japanese starts with that sound. In their version of the game there is the materialization component which is if the thing you say is present it disappears and if it isn't it is created. i.e. in the game Sora says mantoru (mantle) which causes the mantle of the planet to vanish or biichi (beach) which creates a seascape.